# Windows Store App Guidelines on editor applications

Tags: windows-store-apps, user-experience

Most demos and webcasts that introduce and explain Windows Store App are about content consuming applications. Are there any design guidelines for creating editor apps?

Question I have include:

- Is it advisable to take the Metro route here?
- What to do with things like toolbars (think formatting, etc), as the appbar isn't that big, and you're not supposed to include toolbars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on how complicated of an editor application you have in mind.

I think anything heavy weight apps are meant for desktop only and not for metro. For example the Office suite is going to be ran on Desktop mode even on a mobile device according to [Steven Sinofsky](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/09/building-windows-for-the-arm-processor-architecture.aspx): "Within the Windows desktop, WOA includes desktop versions of the new Microsoft Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and OneNote, codenamed “Office 15”". Here WOA refers to Windows On ARM; Windows 8 is going to be tuned towards mobile touch-able devices based on ARM architecture.

Also, according to this [article](http://paidcontent.org/article/419-microsoft-only-we-get-to-use-desktop-mode-in-apps-for-windows-8-on-arm/), you can only have Metro mode apps for ARM; only MS will be able to distribute desktop mode apps.

However, you can still write simple and light weight applications, such as a simple photo editor or notepad I guess. In fact, a google search turned up a [commercial image processing library](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/metro/) for Metro mode.