# Metro-style data input form application

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

[image: http://elysium.codeplex.com/]

[Similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379107/metro-guidelines-on-editor-applications) asking about relatively light-weight data entry / editor application development, which would follow Metro design guidelines.

*The question is do you know of any **samples of a whole app I could look at** to see how a (multi-page) forms application might look like? I.e. [textboxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700391.aspx), checkboxes, comboboxes in Windows 8 style...*

- Maybe [you know to pinpoint one here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples/view/SamplePack#content)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best app I know that showcases some data input is the calendar. Try creating a new appointment. I imagine there are more apps that have input, but I just don't know of any off the top of my head.